# Variables de desarrollo en Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, variables

¿Saben cómo puedo usar variables de desarrollo en C# para xamarin?, he usado **dotnet** en **js** para esto pero no conozco como usar variables de desarrollo en C#.

Comment: A que llamas una variable de desarrollo?

Comment: no entiendo, que es "dotnet en js" ? en que contexto esta esta variable que quieres utilizar ?

Comment: dotnet es una libreria que me permite leer un archivo .env en donde puedo almacenar mi variables de desarrollo proccess.env.connectionadb por ejemplo

Comment: Los archivos .env no son de node.js?

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin no tiene soporte a configuracion adaptable al entorno en el cual estes ejecutand.

Esto es un concepto que si tienes es `asp.net core` en donde puede usar `appsettings.json` y ademas tener `appsettings.dev.json`, `appsettings.staging.json`, pero en Xamarin esto no existe, solo tienes un `config.json`.

Tienes algunos trucos para hacer algo parecido:

[Cross-platform, environment aware configuration files in Xamarin](https://medium.com/@benjamintodts/cross-platform-environment-aware-configuration-files-in-xamarin-232e7d5ddd80)

Basicamente lo que hace ses crear dos `config.json` segun el enviroment copia uno u otro al momento de compilar para leer la config

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es por eso que en la imagen e la solucion del articulo veras una carpeta para `Debug` y otra para `Release`